# Scaphoid Fracture Explained in Layman's Term

Tags: wrist, bone-fractures

I was diagnosed with a "closed displaced fracture of scaphoid of right wrist" today and was wondering exactly what that meant in layman's term.  I can't seem to find a straight forward answer online and the urgent care doctor was in a rush so I didn't get to sit down and talk to him about it.

Comment: I should mention it only felt like a sprain but when the pain didn't go away after a week I was concerned